# IOS 6 Cache Manifest

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, cache-manifest, html5-appcache

I'm noticing some oddities now that I'm checking out the iOS 6 <--> OS X Web Console. It seems that when I update a css file that's supposed to be cached, iOS 6 downloads the new version automatically even if I do not update the manifest file. Under 5.x.x I had expected behavior once I got it all sorted out.

## myapp.appcache

```
CACHE MANIFEST

#Version 1.42505

CACHE:
css/main.css
images/myimage.jpg

etc...
```

The debugging tools make it clear the the file has NOT be redownloaded when there's not a change (~100b "transfered" on the 5kb file).

Furthermore, myimage.jpg will often transfer when neither itself nor the manifest is updated.

Any suggestions or at least confirmations of similar behavior?